# Prisma Relation query with nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js, prisma

Hi I'm new to prisma and I want to connect my job and user table on apllication table.

Thx for your help

my schema is :

```
model Job {
  id          Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  society     String?
  description String?
  application Application[]
}

model User {
  id           Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  email        String        @unique
  name         String?
  applications Application[]
}

model Application {
  id     Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  job    Job  @relation(fields: [jobId], references: [id])
  jobId  Int
  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int
}
```

my code is :

```
 const application = await prisma.application.create({
                data: {
                users: {
                    connect: [{ user: {user}, userId: 1 }],
                },
                jobs: {
                    connect: [{ jobId: 1 }],
                },
                },
            })
```

I dont know why its not working.
Thanks for help

Comment: Don't paste images in posts. Please read how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: well sorry it was not working on my first post i have edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application model, there are no `users` and `jobs`, you should use `user` and `job` instead, when you want to use connect you have to use unique value, id is enough, so use this command:

```
const application = await prismaClient.application.create(
   {
    data: {
        user: {
            connect: {
                id: 1
            }
        },
        job: {
            connect: {
                id: 1
            }
        }
    }
   }
)
```